# Как добавить строки в файл txt flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Из массива строк нужно создать текстовый файл. Пробую через цикл for дописывать строки в конце файла, но получается "обрезка" строк [image: рисунок]

Вот код метода для записи строк из массива:

```
    new RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        //TODO записать в файл
        for(var i = 0; i < character.length; i++){
          String content = character[i];
          CharacterStorage().writeCaracter(content);
        }
      },
      child: new Text('Сохранить в файл',
      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),),
    )
```

А вот код класса для записи файлов:

```
class CharacterStorage {
  String filename = 'characterist.txt';

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return new File('$path/$filename');
  }

  Future<String> readCounter() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();

      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      return 'READING FILE ERROR';
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeCaracter(String content) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$content', mode: FileMode.APPEND);
  }
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы в текстовый файл записывались сроки построчно :) простите за французский

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил использованием метода конкатенации строк и символов \n

```
    new RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
       String content = character.join("\n");
       CharacteristStorage().writeCaracter(content);

      },
      child: new Text('Сохранить в файл',
      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),),
    )
```